# Memory map address space on host from KVM/QEMU guest using virtio-mmio

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, virtio

I am running a direct kernel + Busybox based initrd guest using KVM/QEMU on an aarch64 host.  The host platform is a ZynqMP SoC.  My goal is to memory map the PL of the ZynqMP SoC from the guest VM running on the host using virtio-mmio.

The PL base address can by mapped from the host at the physical address 0xA0000000.

Doing devmem at 0xA0000000 on the host results in the expected value of 0x00000100:

However devmem at 0xA0000000 on the guest results in 0x00000000

My guest kernel has the following configs enabled:

```
CONFIG_VIRTIO_MMIO=y
CONFIG_VIRTIO_MMIO_CMDLINE_DEVICES=y
```

I am adding the `virtio_mmio.device=1K@0xa0000000:48` parameter to the kernel command line of my guest (note: the irq parameter is not relevant in my case, can it be ommitted?)

```
virtio_mmio.device=
                        [VMMIO] Memory mapped virtio (platform) device.

                                <size>@<baseaddr>:<irq>[:<id>]
                        where:
                                <size>     := size (can use standard suffixes
                                                like K, M and G)
                                <baseaddr> := physical base address
                                <irq>      := interrupt number (as passed to
                                                request_irq())
                                <id>       := (optional) platform device id
                        example:
                                virtio_mmio.device=1K@0x100b0000:48:7
```

If I cat /proc/iomem I see virtio-mmio in the list
`a0000000-a00003ff : virtio-mmio.0`

So my main question is why is devmem on 0xA0000000 returning 0x00000000 instead of the expected value of 0x00000100?  Do virtualization drivers need to be configured on the host too?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused about what 'virtio-mmio' is. 'virtio-mmio' is part of the "virtio" virtual device driver specification. virtio-mmio is not an "expose this host device to the guest" mechanism.

Virtio devices can be divided up into:

- a "backend", like 'net', 'block', 'rng', etc, which provides a particular kind of virtual device to the guest.
- a "transport", which is independent of the backed, and defines the mechanism by which the guest sets up the virtio device (configuring it, setting the guest addresses for the ring buffer, etc). Transports include PCI (ie the virtio device is a PCI device), MMIO (the virtio device is a device in the guest's address space somewhere, in the same way that a UART or other simple device is), and other more obscure kinds.

If a QEMU machine type has virtio-mmio transports, then that means that on the QEMU commandline you can plug in a specific backend using an option like `-device virtio-net-backend,...`. The guest can then use this in the same way it would any other emulated device.

Passing the guest kernel "virtio_mmio.device=1K@0xa0000000:48" says "you should expect to see a virtio-mmio transport at this address, using this interrupt". Unless the QEMU model you're running actually put a virtio transport there, then the kernel won't do the right thing. Typically for Arm machine types this isn't necessary, because the device tree passed to the guest kernel should already define where the virtio-mmio transports are.

In general QEMU doesn't support passing through arbitrary memory-mapped host devices. (PCI device passthrough is supported, because that is much easier to manage in terms of handing the device over from the host to the guest and arranging that the guest can't then do bad things to the host with its device access.)

Comment: Appreciate your response. So QEMU doesn't support passing through arbitrary memory-mapped devices, but what about an arbitrary memory window?  I don't need any sort of device/driver layer on top of the memory pass through.  This is an embedded application where an FPGA is interfaced w/ an Arm over AXI bus.  On the host I can interface with the FPGA via /dev/mem.  I am looking how to pass that window exposed by /dev/mem on the host to the guest. Thanks.