# How to memory map address space on host from KVM/QEMU guest

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt, memory-mapping

I have an embedded application running on a Xilinx ZynqMp SoC.  The application running on the PS (processor) memory maps the PL (FPGA) of the SoC over an AXI bus via /dev/mem at some base physical address.

I would like to run this application in a KVM/QEMU VM running on the PS.  This means I will need to somehow expose that memory window available via /dev/mem on the host to the guest VM.

Through some research I thought that virtio-mmio would be the method to do this.  I made some attempts using virtio-mmio but hit a wall, so I asked a question: [Memory map address space on host from KVM/QEMU guest using virtio-mmio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293458/memory-map-address-space-on-host-from-kvm-qemu-guest-using-virtio-mmio)

The response seems to indicate that virtio-mmio is not the method I should be using for this.

If that is the case, what is the method used for exposing a memory space available on the host to a guest VM?  I do not need any sort of device driver/layer on top of this.  I just need raw memory access.